# using ubuntu on hp pavilion20

Tags: 14.04, hp, bios, hp-pavilion

I have tried to install ubuntu 14.04 on my Pavilion20 I was somewhat successful.It seems to be very limited and I have to use the usb hardrive in bios. Are there special switches that I should use in bios?